# How to replace/delete comments or lines starts with particular word in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to delete all comments in an android project, all the comments start with `//` or any other specific characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I'm answering myself I figure it out

In android studio, right-click on the project and select Replace in files, a new window pop up

1 in the first search field tape in this `^\s+//.*$`

2 in the second search field, keep it empty if you just want to delete all the lines that start with `//`

3 now hit replace all button.

if you want to delete other lines that start with different characters, example `@` the expression should be like this `^\s+@.*$`

Answer (score 1):

to delete all the comments just use CTRL + r and write `^\s+//.*$` in first box

**but make sure to check the box Regex**

and in second write no thing and press replace all as shown below
[image]